# Power over integer in python 3

Tags: python

Trying to compute a power of a long integer in Python 3.6.5, and I am getting 0. Is it the expected behavior? Then it contradicts the official docs.

```
In [16]: i
Out[16]: 16777216

In [17]: i**2
Out[17]: 0

In [18]: float(i)**2
Out[18]: 281474976710656.0
```

Comment: Got a repro? https://repl.it/repls/ClumsyWideNormalform

Comment: Cannot reproduce here

Comment: @Caramiriel you can't define as a long in Python 3.6?

Comment: @roganjosh Not sure, but I dont think so? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/ (ah yeah, I was just trying to get it working)

Comment: @Caramiriel Ah, I was curious because your link has `i = 16777216L` which is a syntax error

Comment: Can you please show the output of `type(i)`? I can't reproduce but I'm not sure I doubt that what you're seeing is actually happening.

Comment: 16777216**2 results in 281474976710656. Nothing strange happening here. (Python version 3.5.2).

Comment: We don't know here how value was set to i, so better ask for that info instead of trying to reproduce it in a most obvious way.

Comment: See my answer below. It is best to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen only if `i` is not an `int`. It is possible to find the type of `i` by running:

```
print(type(i))
```

---

In Python, it is possible to define a class that looks like an int, and defines its own `__pow__()` methods. So without further details it is hard to know what is going on.

I have been able to reproduce a similar behavior with:

```
import numpy as np
i = np.int64(4294967296)
print (i**2)
```

But it also prints a warning:

```
__main__:3: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

This behavior is normal with numpy, since it defines a limited integer type with overflow semantics. `np.int64` has only 64 bits, and higher bits from the exponentiation are simply thrown away. Since 4294967296 = 2<sup>32</sup>, then (2<sup>32</sup>)<sup>2</sup> is too big to fit 64 bits. Since the only non-zero bit is bit 64, which is too high, then only zero bits are left after the overflow. This is normal with numpy integer types.

---

When I tried [online python](https://www.python.org/shell/), there was not even a warning when a `numpy.int64` overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reproduce this behaviour, given the small amount of information given, is to create a custom class which overrides the `__pow__` method.
For example,

```
>>> class myInt(int):
...     def __pow__(self,x):
...             return 0
... 
>>> i = myInt(16777216)
>>> i
16777216
>>> i**2
0
>>> float(i)**2
281474976710656.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this question could be closed. Indeed, i variable above is not of a Python int type. Here is the explanation.

```
In [2]: a = np.ndarray((256, 256, 256))
In [3]: i = np.prod(a.shape)
In [4]: i
Out[4]: 16777216
In [5]: type(i)
Out[5]: numpy.int32
```